# bootstrap select option dropdown down arrow not showing

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I use bootstrap select option field with class `form-control`

Here is my code:

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
            <option>Select a Generic Name</option>
            <option value="1">Title 1</option>
            <option value="2">Title 2</option>
 </select>
```

But in dropdown option down arrow icon not displaying

[image: See Image]

CSS:

```
.form-control {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 34px;
padding: 6px 12px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #555;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
-webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
-o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;}
```

What is the main problem to displaying this icon?

Comment: Works fine in JSFiddle. There must be something else going wrong, as the code is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/yvkugjm0/

Comment: Yeah got the problem. Thanks @Varin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i trying to reproduce this issue with your sample code.
But i not faced any specified arrow missing issue in the result.

```css
.form-control {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 34px;
padding: 6px 12px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #555;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
-webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
-o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
            <option>Select a Generic Name</option>
            <option value="1">Title 1</option>
            <option value="2">Title 2</option>
 </select>
```

**Note:**
Make sure the following css is not used for the select dropdown.

```
select {
  /* for Firefox */
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /* for Chrome */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* For IE10 */
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

Hope it will helpful.

Answer (score 130):

If you are using Bootstrap v5 the tag has changed to

```
<select class="form-select">
```

Comment: I guess it helps if I read the right version of the docs. I was looking at the v4 docs 'cause that's what Google found. Gah! Version 5 docs are here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/select/

Answer (score 25):

I was able to solve this issue by slightly modifying [@Sayed Hussainullah Sadat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65662192).

Add **form-select** class next to the **form-control** class.

```
<select class="form-control form-select">
    <option>Select a Generic Name</option>
    <option value="1">Title 1</option>
    <option value="2">Title 2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I found that initially, on upgrading to Bootstrap 5 (from 3), I needed this solution in order to retain the styling on `<select>` elements. This was because the existing CSS was customising them via the `form-control` attribute.

After updating my project's custom CSS to use `select.form-select` where `select.form-control` had previously been used (or applying `form-control`'s styles to `.form-select` too), I was able to use only `form-select` on `<select>` elements to have them render correctly.

Answer (score 8):

It worked for me using the following way:
(The following edit fixed the issue in Chrome )

`select.form-control { -webkit-appearance: menulist; }`

Comment: It works well also in Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

Elements with **"form-control"** class are having an **"appearance"** property set to **'none'** by default. So if you want to display caret(dropdown symbol) for select tag in bootstrap, you have to **override** **BOOTSTRAP** styles with below css.

```css
select.form-control{
    -webkit-appearance: menulist!important;
    -moz-appearance: menulist!important;
    -ms-appearance: menulist!important;
    -o-appearance: menulist!important;
    appearance: menulist!important;
}
```

```html
<!--CDNs of External Libraries to load bootstrap-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!--Select Tag in html-->
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with the bootstrap-select field.
here is a simple class that definitely solves the problem.

Add **custom-select** class next to the **form-control** class.

```
  <select class="form-control custom-select">
        <option>Select a Generic Name</option>
        <option value="1">Title 1</option>
        <option value="2">Title 2</option>
     </select>
```

It will display an **arrow notation**, which may differ in look according to the **browser** and **OS** you are using.